# how do i explain that if (xyz == null) checks are not "protective"

Tags: c#, preconditions

i have a few developers who constantly put If null checks

For example:

```
Run(Order order)
{
  if (order == null) return;
}
```

in their code as they think they are protecting their class if someone passes in a parameter that is null.  I am trying to tell them the flaw in their logic because if someone is passing in null in this case, its most likely an issue with the consumer code and instead of this class throwing an exception and failing fast, it gracefully handles the bad behavior of the consumer and keep chugging away.

another suggestion is to have precondition or guard class that fail fast and throw exceptions.  any thing but ignoring that fact that the consumer probably has some other issue and i am help mask it.

how do i get folks to appreciate the fact that your class shouldn't be so forgiving.  if someone doesn't pass in good data, they should be told.

any good articles or suggestions to help me get this point across?

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question; it's way too subjective in its current form. Besides, you're wrong :-)

Comment: i rephrased . . why do you say i am wrong ??

Comment: Hmm, voted to reopen after the edits dialed down the tone.

Comment: If your constructor contract requires a non-null argument, you should instead: 

if (order == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("order");

Comment: @oo - because in its original form (edited is better) your post implied that it's **always** a bad idea to check for nulls. And that's wrong, because it depends on a use case - I completely agree with answers by `John Ferminella` and `JS Bangs` below.

Comment: Didn't you just explain why? :)

Comment: You should totally throw an exception because whatever code runs next could assume the Run(order) method didn't fail. Holes in the chain. Even if by construction of the entire application it works okay now, it'll become a future bug when someone tries to call this same Run method from another context and it fails and they don't know. You'll have something else fail on down the chain and good luck finding out what that was when it's not even shown in the call stack any longer.

Comment: @jdk: That should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your class cannot accept `null` arguments, then the best thing to do is this:

```
if (arg == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
```

This is vastly preferable to getting a `NullPointerException` deeper down the stack. In the worst case scenario, you'll cache that `null` somewhere and won't actually trigger the exception until much later, and see how much fun you'll have debugging the problem *then*.

And as others have stated, sometimes the contract says that `null` is okay. In that case, having a guard clause around some parts of the code is correct--although even then I'd say that the best design would be to add an overload without the optionally-null arguments.

Comment: if the contract says null is ok, then you should probably be using a nullable to more explicitly indicate this.

Answer (score 7):

It really depends on the precise situation. It's rarely advisable to give general suggestions like "don't put null checks in your code", as you seem to be indicating. The contract of the class should define what's legit and what isn't. But if the contract makes it clear that passing in null is not acceptable, then an exception is indeed an appropriate response.

Answer (score 3):

As everyone else has said, it is vastly preferable to fail early than to get mysterious problems in production because the function didn't do anything when it was expected to.  if the function returns for null arguments, as in your example).

Even if the function doesn't return and just throws a `NullReferenceException`, it's eaiser to solve a bug when you know that an argument was null.  If a function throws a `NullReferenceException`, you have no idea what was `null` or whose fault it was.

I'd like to add that `ArgumentNullException` takes a parameter for a reason.

It is better to write

```
if(myArg == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("myArg");
```

than to throw an `ArgumentNullException` without a `paramName`.

This way, if you have an exception from a function that takes five parameters, you'll know which of the parameters caused the problem.  This is especially important if you cannot attach a debugger.  (For example, on a production web server or an end-user machine)

If you're writing many functions, this can be a lot of overhead, especially since there's no IntelliSense for the strings.  I wrote a code snippet to generate these checks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Check for null arguments</Title>
            <Shortcut>tna</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for throw new ArgumentNullException</Description>
            <Author>SLaks</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>Parameter</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Paremeter to check for null</ToolTip>
                    <Default>value</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[if ($Parameter$ == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("$Parameter$");
        $end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't watched through it, but [eiffel.com has 2 presentations](http://www.eiffel.com/developers/presentations/) (slides+audio) on the topic of *design by contract*. These guys have [invented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract#History) the concept, so if anyone can explain it it's them :-)

Answer (score 2):

Code contracts in .net 4.0 will hopefully make this behavior much more consistent.
Any articles which talk about code contracts will help get the idea across, and in the future, this kind of syntax will provide the method.

http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/11/11/introduction-to-code-contracts-melitta-andersen.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that Code Contracts will not be available in the Professional edition of visual studio 2010. This will prevent if from really taking off.

Comment: The actual contracts are a CLR feature, which will be common across all versions ( Mono included, eventually ). What is limited to team studio seems to be an application which examines code and checks for contract compliance. Runtime checking will be available everywhere.

Comment: The Contract classes are indeed in the BCL (System.Diagnostics.Contracts) but they don't actually do anything without the tools; I've tried it in VS2010 Premium beta2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608406/does-visual-studio-2010-premium-include-the-contract-tools

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can't tell people why a practice like this is wrong - they have to figure it out for themselves. But you could help them get there by coming up with some unit test that causes some nasty failure due to this problem, and make them debug the error.

Comment: You are assuming that they write unit tests.  The kind of developers who write unit tests will usually throw exceptions already. (I hope)

Answer (score 1):

If the method's contract specifies that its arguments should not be null, then the right thing to do is to make it explicit, by using an Assert, like this:

```
Debug.Assert( item != null, "Null items are not supported );
```

This will fail fast when the executable is built using a debug configuration, but will present zero performance degradation when built using a release configuration.

Comment: If you're so worried about performance that you're unwilling to compare a reference to `null`, you should be writing assembler.  Besides, are you saying that bugs do not happen in production?

Comment: Not to mention the implicit null checks on every member access that are there either way...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a question about how best write code that is manageable.  It is my new belief that you must assume ignorance of all consumers of your code.  I have gotten myself into trouble by assuming I or someone with deep knowledge would be consuming my code.  The only thing I would add to throwing an exception is creating custom exceptions as well as leaving breadcrumbs in the inner exception. I believe strongly in giving your developers a chance to run down the issue especially if it is due to data.  I spend most of my time looking for the data that breaks my code and if you can leave hints you will save weeks in a year.

Answer (score -2):

Well first of all, you are unequivocally incorrect.  You are embracing a very serious logical fallacy.  You want your code to be correct by virtue of the code assuming that everything happening around it is correct.  As if correctness was some kind of magical pixie dust that you just need to spray everywhere.

All bugs are or seem stupid once they are exposed.  But its checks like this that tease them out to expose themselves.  Until then, bugs are invisible.  And for large and complex enough projects, you don't know who will find the bug or under what conditions they will be found.  Code which is architected for resilience typically has checks like this all over the place and also check the return values for every function which have to include error values.  So you end up encoding a "I can't do that because the sub-functions I rely on are not working" semantic that is actually handled properly.  The great value of this is that you can usually implement work arounds or self-aware debug instrumentation quite easily.  *Why* you want to do things like this is because the most difficult bugs usually rely on both of those properties to debug properly.

Learn some lessons from your developers.  They put checks like that in there, because they don't know why sometimes they get strange results from functions.  You call them naive or overly cautious because of one narrow piece of knowledge that you have that they don't.  But when you are debugging something nasty you are going to wonder why you don't have such checks in your code, and you are going to end up looking just as naive for not being able to spot the bug in first place.

In short: No code is made robust by assuming robustness about the environment around them.

Comment: You are wrong.  His point is that fail-fast code makes it much easier to find bugs in the code that calls it, and he is very very right.

Comment: Wait; which side are you defending?

Comment: Failing fast is only useful for a developer with the source code and debugger right in front of him/her, and if they are making a really really simple kind of error. Testers, beta-program people, and developers who are working in other parts of the code will also run into this. And if they fail fast, what are they going to do about it?

If you are getting bad parameters, then what you want to know is *WHY* you are getting bad parameters.  The *CALL SITE* will know more about that then the function which tries to consume the bad parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you look at the example the poster provided, that almost certainly just swallows up the error into a black hole from which no information will escape.  That allows the error to last much longer.  

On the other hand, if the protection code at least logs a message saying what happened ("null argument in XXX, all bets are off!  investigate!!!") in a log that someone will actually check, then I might agree with you.

Comment: Well keep in mind that the original poster has predeclared his prejudice on this matter.  So the fact that he showed to useless example code should not be taken as evidence of anything.

Of course you should have very descriptive failures.  Returning an enum like: APP_ERR_NULL_FOO_OBJECT which the call site then notices, potentially cleans up and logs as errLogf("Error: %s foo(%d)", errString (APP_ERR_NULL_FOO_OBJECT), parameterToInitFoo); or something like that, then that is ideal.

You can't learn or appreciate the value of this with the questioner's attitude/point of view.

Comment: @Dan: That's extremely poor design.  You don't want to replicate each parameter check in the call sites.  That would be relying on all call sites.  Being NULL is not the only way such a parameter or the function itself could go wrong.  I didn't literally mean you should call errString(APP_ERR...).  Obviously it would be something like errString(ret) which would correspond to whichever error was returned by the called function.