# use MORE structs?

Tags: c#, .net, class, struct

There have been several questions over the past few days about the proper use of *null*; here are three (one is mine):

- [Best Practice: Should functions return null or an empty object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626597/best-practice-should-functions-return-null-or-an-empty-object)
- [null objects vs. empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628434/null-objects-vs-empty-objects)
- [how do i explain that if (xyz == null) checks are not “protective”.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647666/i-hate-when-people-use-if-xyz-null-and-think-they-are-being-protective-h)

While reading and thinking about this issue, the thought occured to me: why not use `struct` instead of `class`?  (I then read some of the many questions about just that.)

One **big** benefit of a `struct` (in this context) is that *it can't be null*, so there is never a need to check against `null`.  And as an added bonus, if you really want a null `struct` you can do that too with some extra syntax (`T?`) and the `Nullable<>` type.  (Too bad reference types didn't work like this too!)

But `struct`s are passed by value which kills performance.  Well, first, code should be "right" (whatever *that* might mean) and then fast.  However, there are several ways to avoid that overhead where it really matters: `ref` parameters, nullable parameters, place the `struct` in some other class, say `List<>`.

True, with `struct`s, you can't create a class hierarchy, but "inheritence is overused".  And you can implement interfaces.

Using more `struct`-based objects could make writing multi-threaded code easier.

Are there any more infrequently cited advantages to `struct`s?  Do any of these considerations even come close to putting a dent in `class`'s massive "head start"?

Comment: Who else is hoping we'll get non-nullable reference types (Spec# style) in a future version of C#? It's really unfortunate that it would need a CLR change to do properly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big limitation (IMO) of a `struct` is that it ought to be immutable.

I have several times defined and used a user-defined struct, for the reason you suggested (ie. because a struct can't be null); but I was then often (until I learned to never make them anything but immutable) burned by modifying a copy (sometimes an unnamed temporary copy) of a struct instance, instead of modifying the instance itself.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should just stick to the [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), being creative like this will just get you into trouble, and probably make the code less maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

If you start using structs in weakly types scenarios (like assigning to an object type) `Object o = structValue;` or `Object o = new mystruct();` or `Object o = default(mystruct);` etc. the values are boxed onto the heap, and they are also unboxed when used. This is a potential drawback because it affects performance. See info from Microsoft about [boxing and unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: Yes, the one exception being generics can still be weakly typed - for example "List<object>" provides no advantage but still might be used to stored struct values and boxing/unboxing still occurs.